# Boundaries of finite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I'm currently studying the simplest models of potentials in QM, and I've run across an apparent inconsistency in my textbook: when describing a finite potential as a piecewise function, I've noticed the author defines the value of the potential twice in the boundaries, as follows:

$$V(x) = \begin{cases}V_0, \ \ |x|\leq a/2\\0, \ \ |x|\geq a/2\end{cases}$$

where $a$ is the width of the well and $V_0<0$. Does this make sense? Intuitively, you'd think you need to remove one of the two equalities. Otherwise, the particle is subject to two different values of the potential at the same point (I know this is incorrect wording in QM but mind me, this is not a formal question). If this is the case, which one of the two equalities should be removed? As usual, thank you for your time.

EDIT: Specified the sign of $V_0$

Comment: You are correct that the question is mistakenly doubly defining those points inconsistently. However, it will be of no consequence, so you are free to choose as you like, as long as you choose symmetrically, to allow symmetry analysis to simplify your solution. On an unrelated note, if it is a potential well, then it is customary to have the insides of the well be of zero potential and the outsides to have positive $V_0$ potential, extending all the way to infinity both ways. The expression you have seems to be for a square barrier.

Comment: When an author is sloppy about something so simple, it makes you wonder about their ability to do the complicated stuff correctly.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): The value of the potential on a measure-zero set usually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this definition of finite potential well is not well-defined. In the best traditions of quantum mechanics boundary condition should be omitted, because particle state at these points are undefined. So, it should be :

$$ V(x)={\begin{cases}
0~{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if }}x\lt -a/2 ~\lor x \gt a/2 \\
V_{0}~~~~~~~~~~~~~{\text{if }}x \gt -a/2 ~\land x\lt a/2 \\
\text{undefined}~{\text{if }}x=-a/2 \lor x=a/2
\end{cases}}
$$

"Undefined" part is usually omitted in classical texts of quantum mechanics, or is included into one of conditions, because it's singularity. But surely we can't include it in both cases, because our well will have ambiguos definition.